# How does PHP handle multiple clients?

Tags: php, apache, http

When a client requests a PHP file, does the server execute the code, serve the client and close the script? Or does the server run a single instance of the PHP script from boot to shutdown? If not, does Apache start a new thread/run a new "program" for each client?

If multiple clients are connected (HTTP Long Polling) at the same time, can the server hold back its response to all of them until it gets a specific HTTP get request from another client?

Comment: You can not handle multiple users at the same time you should use javascript Because of PHP not support from Run the same programs and not support thread.

Comment: To your first question, yes. The server executes the code, delivers the output and closes the file. Each connection results in an Apache thread being started to run PHP and the thread is destroyed when the script is finished.